# how to count a row multiple times in case

Tags: mysql, sql

product table:

```
shrimp
lobster
beef
special1
special2
```

I also have a transaction table that for each row contains a product from the above table.  I would like to do a count of the transaction table so I see how much shrimp, lobster and beef went out.  However, a transaction row with special1 should count as 1x shrimp and 1x lobster and special2 should count as 1x shrimp, 1x lobster and 1x beef.

What's the best SQL statement that can help me accomplish this OR how can I create a rules table to help me achieve proper counts?

Some samples:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


insert into product (product_id, descr) values ('1','shrimp dish');
insert into product (product_id, descr) values ('2','beef dish');
insert into product (product_id, descr) values ('3','lobster dish');
insert into product (product_id, descr) values ('4','special1 dish');



CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into ticket (product_id, price) values ('2',4);
insert into ticket (product_id, price) values ('3',6);
insert into ticket (product_id, price) values ('4',11);
```

Here I would like a query on ticket that gets me the total sales ($21) and that I sold 2x shrimp, 2x lobster  (because special1 takes up 1x shrimp and 1xlobster to make)

Comment: more clarity required, show some sample data and what output you needed.

Comment: this question is begging for improvement

Comment: Can you please provide sample output data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, doing it in columns is much easier, see [my SQLfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebe99/3):

```
SELECT iname ingredient, SUM(amount) amount_used 
FROM tickets
INNER JOIN products    ON pid=tpid
INNER JOIN prodingred  ON pi =pid
INNER JOIN ingredients ON iid=ii
GROUP BY iname
```

You should, however introduce two more tables `ingredients` and `prodingred` that define how much of which ingredient is being used for which dish. Having proper tables will make the whole thing much easier scalable than defining complicated `CASE` constructs in your `SELECT` statements.

I also introduced the column `amount` in the alloction table `prodingred` in which you can place the *actual amount* (in g or kg) of each ingredient for each product sold. This will make your results much more accurate than just saying "I need 1 shrimps for product A".

**UPDATE**

If you also want to see the **cost contributions** of each tickets to your used ingredients then your idea of adding a column `costshare` to the `prodingred` table is a good starting point. If you make this column a float (or double) column you could actually express the cost share of each ingredient in each meal (product) as shown below:

```
| pi | ii | amount | costshare |
|----|----|--------|-----------|
|  1 |  1 |      1 |         1 |
|  2 |  2 |      1 |         1 |
|  3 |  3 |      1 |         1 |
|  4 |  1 |      1 |       0.3 |
|  4 |  2 |      1 |       0.7 |
|  5 |  1 |      1 |       0.2 |
|  5 |  2 |      1 |       0.5 |
|  5 |  3 |      1 |       0.3 |
```

Doing the sums is then very simple:

```
SELECT iname ingredient, SUM(amount) amount_used, 
       SUM(ROUND(tprice*costshare*100)/100.) tprice_contribution
FROM tickets
INNER JOIN products    ON pid=tpid
INNER JOIN prodingred  ON pi =pid
INNER JOIN ingredients ON iid=ii
GROUP BY iname
```

Which will get you (see my [updated SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00c5ce/6))

```
|   iname | amount_used | tprice_contribution |
|---------|-------------|---------------------|
|    beef |           1 |                   6 |
| lobster |           2 |                11.7 |
|  shrimp |           1 |                 3.3 |
```

Comment: Thanks but adding sum(tprice) gives me the wrong ticket totals.

Comment: Tentatively solved this by adding a calcamount to the prodingred table whereby it is 1 for every unique product_id and first ingredient but 0 for every additional ingredient.

Comment: Well, yes, if you are looking for the cost contribution of your tickets to the actual ingredients used then that is the easiest way. You could improve it though, look at my updated answer.